# Python version problems Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: 22.04, python, python3, tkinter

My goal is it to install [tkinter](https://packages.debian.org/de/bookworm/amd64/python3-tk/download) for python 3.11. I have successfully installed and used 3.11 from the deadsnakes ppa. But when I run

```
sudo dpkg -i python3-tk_3.11.2-3_amd64.deb
```

I get:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-tk:amd64:
python3-tk:amd64 depends on python3 (>= 3.10.8-0~); however:
Version of python3 on system is 3.10.6-1~22.04.
```

Now I though ok I will update the python version... But:

```
sudo apt install python3.10
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
python3.10 is already the newest version (3.10.12-1~22.04.2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

And when I check my installed python version I don't see where the second python 3.10 version should be installed:

```
ll /usr/bin/ | grep python


-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     5913032 Jun 11  2023 python3.10*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     6714392 Dez  8 19:56 python3.11*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root          34 Dez  8 19:56 python3.11-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.11-config*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    30337952 Dez  8 19:56 python3.11d*
```

`python3.10 --version` also returns: `Python 3.10.12`

So how can I configure my system that, dpkg checks that there is a valid python installation?

I also created already a symlink so that `python` maps to `python3.11`

Thank you in advance

Comment: The PPA should be added properly instead of installing debs separately

Comment: @DanielT tried this first, but it seems that this bookworm ppa is broken for 22.04 LTS. It returns: "The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/bookworm-team/bookworm/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file."

Comment: And I did not find an other ppa which delivers tkinter in 3.11.x. But I can not be the first which wants tkinter and ubuntu 22.04 and python 3.11...

Comment: The https://launchpad.net/~bookworm-team/+archive/ubuntu/bookworm is **not** a *maintained* PPA, so unless you're using an *unsupported* system OR exploring security problems intentionally; why are you trying to use it??  The "*does not have a Release file*" is expected! for *unmaintained* PPAs; did you perform your security checks on the 3rd party *personal package archive* before adding?  PPAs are not security checked, with it your responsibility.

Comment: Python3.11 may be installed from the standard repos, no ppas needed.  The associated tkinter for both 3.10 and 3.11 are from package python3-tk  Just don't try to make python3.11 your system default python.

Answer (score 0):

**Use a virtual environment to resolve your issue.**

- **Use a Python Version Manager**: Consider using a Python version manager like Pyenv or asdf to manage multiple Python versions on your system. These tools allow you to install and switch between different Python versions easily, and you can create virtual environments with any installed Python version.

Let me know if any further information is needed.